# python unittest value of os.getcwd() changes when running individual test vs running pytest as whole

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have a test which uses `os.getcwd()` to determine the path to a file. When running `pytest -k test_name`, I see the value of `os.getcwd()` to be my project root where as when running `pytest --cov --cov-report html` the same test fails because the value returned by `os.getcwd()` is some other path, some nested directories inside the folder test (containing all the tests) in my project root.

Is there an easy way to standardise this behaviour or getting the result of `os.getcwd` as when running for individual tests by some other library method such that I don't need to write long path names in my source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) returns a current working directory, which means that any part of the script or other module may perform actions, that will make it's value change.

Depending on your purpose you can use value of [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) (along with helpers provided by `os.path`) to determine path to your module/test in the filesystem.

Comment: thanks but can you explain the theory behind it why is my `cwd` changing when running `pytest` as whole ?

Comment: I am not that familiar with `pytest` but a [glimpse at source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/search?q=os.chdir&unscoped_q=os.chdir) reveals quite a few places where `os.chdir` is called.

Comment: This is correct: use `__file__`. It will remain static regardless of where your script (including `pytest`'s runner) is executed from